# Посчитать в функции скидку

Tags: javascript, функции

Надо записать метод расчета цены с учётом скидки. У меня выбивает ошибку, хотя я вроде правильно делаю, что неправильно?

```js
const price = {
 price: 10,
 discount: '15%',
 getPrice: function () {
  return this.price;
 }
 getDiscount: function () {
  return this.discount / this.price;
 }
}
```

Comment: запятую после первой функции добавьте

Comment: А JS умеет делить строку "15%" на число?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов логический смысл деления процента скидки на стоимость тоже интересен :)

Comment: @teran ну вдруг там очень хитрый магазин? :-D

Answer (score 2):

```js
const price = {
 price: 10,
 discount: 0.15, // 15%, а потом * 100 если что-то не так
 getPrice: function () {
  return this.price;
 }, // Тут забыли ,
 getDiscount: function () {
  return this.discount / this.price;
 }
}
```

Comment: А '15%' / 10 не смуащает

Comment: @IgorOgnichenko, чуть-чуть, но ошибки не выдаёт хотя бы :) Изменил на **0.15**

Comment: Следующим вопросом было бы почему NaN ))

Comment: @IgorOgnichenko, аха :))

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```js
const price = {
 price: 10,
 discount: '15%',
  
 getPrice: function () {
  return this.price;
 },
  
 getDiscount: function () {  
  return parseInt(this.discount) / +this.price;
 }
}

console.log(price.getDiscount())
```